# jQuery: Hide function breaks after sorting content of divs

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, hide

I found some jQuery code to sort divs numerically or alphabetically according to the content. On top of this I added a function to be able to hide a div, bound to an on click listener. Hiding the divs works just fine, sorting the divs works just fine. However, if I sort the divs first, and then I try to hide them, it doesn't work. They sort fine, they just can't be hidden. No error code, nothing.

You can see the example at work here:

```
<div class="wrap">
<button id="alphBnt">Alphabetical</button>
<button id="numBnt">Numerical</button>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <button>Hide</button>
    <h1>B<h1>
    <h2>10.35</h2>  
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <button>Hide</button>
    <h1>A<h1>
    <h2>100.05</h2>
  </div>    
</div>
```

```
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#alphBnt').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});

$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});

$(".box button").on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this).parent());
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/2031/

Thanks.

Comment: Found the solution by inserting the even listener inside the sort functions like so https://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/2041/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to attach your hide events within the click functions

```
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#alphBnt').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);

    $(".box button").on('click', function () {
        console.log($(this).parent());
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});

$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);

    $(".box button").on('click', function () {
        console.log($(this).parent());
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, was the same thing I ended up doing on my edit yesterday. Didn't know how to close this thing or whatever. Thanks for the reply either way. This is the correct way of doing it.